# Why does global pointers behave erratically in this function?

Tags: c

I've tried to write a program that uses global pointers to track down local variables, but when I use the right syntaxes, it doesn't run.

When I alter the syntaxes, the program yields correct results. I don't fully understand the mechanism behind it, and hoping that more experienced coders could explain it. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int *q;
int *u;
int *p;
void test () {
    printf("Insert #1?\t"); scanf("%d", &u); 
/*should be scanf("%d", u) for u is a pointer*/ 
    printf("Insert #2?\t"); scanf("%d", &p); 
/*should be scanf("%d", p) for p is a pointer*/ 
}
int main () {
    test ();
    printf("%d\n", u); 
/*should be printf("%d\n", *u) since I am trying to dereference the value of u*/
    printf("%d\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", q);
}
```

The output should be 3 numbers, 2 first numbers are inputs from user, and the third one should be a nonsense number since the 3rd pointer is not pointing anywhere.

Update: It works!!!!! Thank you so much for your help :).

Comment: So.. what this line is supposed to do: `scanf("%d", &u);` ? Your comments are correct (but not complete..). Why are you showing us a broken code?

Comment: Hi, scanf("%d", &u) sends inputs from user into the variable u, but u is a pointer, so I can't understand what's going on.

Comment: The pointers `p`, `q` and `u` are uninitialized, they don't point to a valid memory address. That's why `scanf("%d", u)` would be undefined behavior. When you use `scanf("%d", &u)` you misuse the pointer as an `int` variable; here it should be `int u;` instead of `int *u;`

Comment: @TrươngQuốcQuân Please [edit] your question to add more information or clarification instead of writing comments.

Comment: An `int*` is a different type of variable, it contains the address of an `int`. By scanning into `&u` you are scanning the address it will point to, which will probably be nothing.

Comment: Hi @Bodo, how could the computer recognize a pointer as a normal variable? I know pointers are variables but shouldn't "int* p" be enough for the machine to recognize p as a pointer and therefore should've sent errors?

Comment: You need to learn what the pointer is. This is explain in any C book. This not the programming problem, you need to read a bit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with global variables. There are multiple problems here but the most pressing error is that you are attempting to use uninitialised pointers. **This never works**. You need to understand pointers before you can use them properly.

In particular, if you have a declaration like this:

```
int *x;
```

Then, *no matter what you do*, you first need to assign a valid pointer to `x`<sup>1</sup>.

In your case the error is compounded by the fact that you’re using `scanf` wrong. Luckily the solution here is very easy: Don’t declare pointers. Instead, declare `int` variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int q;
int u;
int p;

void test () {
    printf("Insert #1?\t"); scanf("%d", &u); 
    printf("Insert #2?\t"); scanf("%d", &p); 
}

int main () {
    test();
    printf("%d\n", u); 
    printf("%d\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", q);
}
```

Ironically the comments in your original code already point out the issue, they just suggest a wrong solution. It’s a bit of a mystery where these comments are from. ;-)

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically the only exception is for statically allocated pointers, which are correctly zero-initialised and can therefore be used in null pointer comparisons.

Comment: I know the basic syntaxes but I don't have a deep understanding... due to the nature of our syllabus (which is to give general understanding of the syntax, emphasizing on building algorithms and mathematics). That's why I know what to write (hence the comments), but not the underlying things that happen under the hood. Do you recommend any other books besides K&R and C for Dummies?

Answer (score 1):

Your global variables are the pointers to the ints, not the ints themselves. When you read in the values, you change where in memory `u` points to, not the value of `u`.

You should replace it with either `scanf("%d", u);` or change the declaration to `int u`.

You need to be careful taking pointer values from the user. Otherwise, you could risk things like null pointer dereferencing. For instance, Entering `0` when you `scanf("%d", &u);`, it would then make the value of `u` be `NULL`.

Comment: This would still do nothing and cause a crash/freeze if the pointer isn't initialized to a valid address.

Comment: I know :) that's why it's so weird :) but Bodo gave me suggestions that I should try now. I'll update if you want to chase this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers need to point to something, such as another variable, or memory allocated dynamically with `malloc()`.

You can't use `scanf()` to read directly into a pointer. You can use it to read into what the pointer points to.

So you can write something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int q;
int *qp = &q;
int *up;
int p;
int *pp = &p;
void test () {
    printf("Insert #1?\t"); scanf("%d", up); 
    printf("Insert #2?\t"); scanf("%d", pp); 
}
int main () {
    up = malloc(sizeof(*up));
    test ();
    printf("%d\n", *up); 
    printf("%d\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", q);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment to the question, a pointer is a type that holds the address to another variable of some type, so `int*` holds an address for a variable of type `int`. In your case, `&u` is referring to the address of `u`, so you're trying to scan a number into a pointer which won't work. You should change it to only `u` so it will scan to the variable it points too, but it needs to point to a valid variable in the first place. Here is a valid example:

```
int someNumber = 5;
int* u = &someNumber; // u points to a valid address statically allocated
scanf("%d", u); // Scans the number inputed to someNumber because u points to it
getchar(); // Avoid buffer overflow
printf("%d\n", *u); // A * dereferences u - gets the value of the variable it's pointing to
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pointers have no value assigned to them.